# SOQL query to get products related to a case

Tags: apex, soql, schema-builder

Good afternoon.

I am confused as to why I can see a Lookup relationship on Schema Builder, linking Case and Product (Product2?) objects, but when I click on "Open Resource => Case.obj" that reference field is not available.

As part of the Superbadge process I had to relabel Product2 as Equipment/Equipments, but none of these shown either.

Why is this reference field showing on Schema Builder but not elsewhere? Does anybody know what kind of query would show me the products related to a particular case?

[image]

Following Phil's answer, I checked again but I cannot see the reference to Product

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [object model documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cases_fields.htm&type=5). The `Product` field links to a Product from Case. So there's a related list of Cases for the Product object.

Comment: Thanks Phil, it looks like "This field is only available if entitlements are set up to include products.", I guess that explains why I cannot see it in this particular case.